# Slow connection for normal users after setting up VPN for specific user only

Tags: networking, internet, dns, vpn

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS as a server&router and recently I've set up a VPN connection (with private internet access) for a specific user (user: pia). I've configured the server to use PIA's DNS servers but ever since setting it up I've noticed significantly reduced internet speed for **regular users**, e.g. when running speedtest

Interestingly enough running speedtest as pia (sudo -u pia speedtest-cli) gives acceptable results given that it is going through a VPN, and is significantly faster than for other users. Also internet speeds from other clients behind the router aren't affected.

I get the feeling that for some reason the speedtest traffic by regular users is routed through the US, back to a server in my hometown Amsterdam, as it shows a latency of 260ms with a server distance of some 3km.
Also when I ping google.com as a regular user i get:

`64 bytes from yul02s05-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.13.142): icmp_seq=1 ttl=53time=116 ms`

while as user pia I get:

`64 bytes from dh-in-f113.1e100.net (209.85.203.113): icmp_seq=1 ttl=48 time=32.2 ms`

However if I ping 209.85.203.113 as a regular user I get latencies around 22ms, so at least dns lookup is inefficient.

Any clues are very welcome.

Comment: What network layer config do you use for VPN, TUN or TAP?

Comment: The VPN interface is tun1 (actually running a VPN server as well on tun0). I suppose this means the network layer config is TUN?

Comment: Yes, it's a TUN. Your problem sounds like, users are using the VPN for all traffic, so double check if the VPN client users use have route all the traffic through the VPN.

Comment: Thanks. When I curl ipecho.net/plain as a regular user I get my normal WAN ip-adress whereas when I run it as the VPN user I get the VPN ip. This should confirm that only the vpn user is actually routed through the VPN right?

Comment: Well, its look like working fine for me. The only other thing could cause this is the ISP upload & download setting. I.E my company has a corporate line, that means if any given time, the upload request higher bandwidth (i.e. sending data through VPN), that bandwidth is taken from download speed. I see most of the time 120mbps UP & 80mbps DOWN, our line is 200mbps UP&DOWN. So check that's the case.